# How to count total shares from Facebook, Twitter, G+, etc like they did in mashable.com

Tags: jquery, social-networking, share-button

Does anybody know how http://mashable.com put up a slick social widget that counts the number of total shares from different social networking sites? 
I just want to know if you can do this by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make individual request to each api (via PHP, as Google and Twitter do not allow Cross Domain) - create a wrapper class call, this will calculate individual counts over you server.

Similar Implementation (php) - http://www.saladappstore.com/page/social-analytics

To use jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/sanchit_gupta/f9kqm/

```
(function() {

var url = "http://www.cnn.com";
$.getJSON('http://api.sharedcount.com/?url=' + url, function(data){
    $('body').append('<p></p>Google Plus ' + JSON.stringify(data['GooglePlusOne']));
    $('body').append('<p></p>Twitter ' + JSON.stringify(data['Twitter']));
    $('body').append('<p></p>Facebook ' + JSON.stringify(data['Facebook']['total_count']));
});
```

})();